# How can I show an element that's being hidden in an overflow-hidden element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a part of my component that uses overflow hidden and inside I have a menu that toggles. I need this menu in this position but currently when it shows it is mostly hidden because of the overflow-hidden. Is there a way I can make this show fully even with it being placed inside the overflow-hidden?

I am using Tailwind CSS and this is a Vue component:

```
<div class="grid justify-between grid-cols-5 -mx-4 overflow-auto max-h-64">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index" class="px-4 py-4">
        <div :class="isSelected(item.fileUrl) ? 'border-2' : ''" class="relative w-full h-24 overflow-hidden border-green-500 cursor-pointer hover:border-2 group">
            <img :src="item.fileUrl" class="w-auto h-full mx-auto max-w-none" />
            <i v-if="isSelected(item.fileUrl)" class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 mb-1 ml-2 text-xl text-green-500 fas fa-square-check" />
            <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 flex items-center justify-center w-6 h-6 mt-2 mr-2 bg-gray-500 rounded-full opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 group-hover:bg-opacity-100" @click.stop="toggleMenu(item)">
                <font-awesome-icon :icon="['far', 'ellipsis-vertical']" class="text-base text-base-content" />
                <jet-media-dropdown-menu v-if="isSelected(item.fileUrl)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow-hidden=false
```

Try with this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).